# Stuttering SignalR When Using IIS

Tags: web, iis, websocket, signalr

I am using ASP .NET SignalR to create a realtime game in the browser. It seems to run fine, other than occasional stutters on the display output.

I first noticed this when I deployed my application to a virtual PC in the cloud. To rule out bandwidth issues, I then deployed it to another virtual PC running locally.

Even when running the application from a virtual PC locally, I still get the stutters.

This issue does not happen when I run the application on local host using IIS express.

This makes me think that the issue has something to do with IIS, since both the cloud virtual PC and local virtual have this in common and local host does not.

After Googling I found lots of people advising to check certain settings in IIS.

These websocket settings were listed as possible culprits:
[image: IIS websocket settings]

I don’t see any issues there though.

Another suggestion was to check the queue length in the advanced settings of the App Pool. Currently it is 1000. I believe that this is enough, as according to Perfmon, the number of requests received peeks at about 100 per second and sent at 80.
[image: Queue Settings IIS]
[image: Perfmon]

Has anyone else got any ideas?

I am using SignalR for ASP .NET 2.4.1 and IIS 10

Thanks

Comment: I noticed that you are using .net 2.4 but the CLR of the application pool is suitable for applications above version 4.0. Not sure if this will affect performance, but you can modify it. It is also recommended that you can modify some attributes in the ASP module to improve application performance. Diable asp debugging, set Threads Per Processor Limit to 50, reduce the queue length of asp(not app pool).

Comment: I am using .NET framework 4.7.2. 2.4 is the version of the Signal R Library.
Debugging was already is disabled 
Increased thread limit, didn't see any difference.
Can you explain why reducing the queue length helps? Shouldn't I be increasing it?
Also I found lots of search results about how to change the App pool queue length but  nothing on the asp queue length. How do I do this?

Comment: This value represent how often IIS will send “server too busy” message to the users when ASP is receiving high number of requests. If the queue length time is too high, IIS will send “busy message” to users with longer delay, which make the users feel that the server may be out of service.  Too low queue length will cause the server send “server busy message” quite often, consuming resources of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I blamed IIS wrongly, after further investigation I found the issue is most likely due to high CPU usage.

I ran Perfmon, and looked at the '%Processor Time' counters, and noticed that the application is frequently at 100%.